# "housing prices" vs. "house prices"

Tags: word-usage

Searching for "housing prices" on Google always gets "house prices" recommendation

[image]

Does it indicate I should use "house prices" when talking about that topic?

Ngram Viewer shows both are common.

[image]

Do they mean same thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If used correctly, "house prices" refers to the price of houses, and not other kinds of housing. Other places to live are apartments and condominiums, and maybe others, which might be included in "housing prices".